# Scraping BRfares for train fares

Tags: web-scraping

I am looking for advise. The following website

http://brfares.com/#home

provides fares information for UK train lines. I would like to use it to build a database of travel costs for seasons tickets from different locations. I have never done this kind of thing before but have experience with Python/Bash scripting and some HTML.

Viewing the source code for a typical query the actual fair information is not displayed in `index.html`. Can anyone provide a pointer as to how to go about scraping (a new word for me) the information.

Answer (score 1):

This is the url for the query : `http://brfares.com/querysimple?orig=SUY&dest=0415&rlc=`

the response is a json object.

First you need to build a lookup table of all destinations codes. you can use the following link to do that `http://brfares.com/ac_loc?term=`. Do it for all the letters in the alphabet and then parse for a unique list.

Then you take them by the pair, execute the json query, parse the returned json and feed the data to a database.

Now you can do whatever you want with that database.